# Create "custom" Customer attributes in registration of Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, attributes

I want to create **some Custom Customer Attributes** (like "**company**", or "**prefered color**") during the **registration of a new customer in my web shop Magento 1.7.0.2**

I have found an extension that creates custom attributes for customer, customer address and category.**Hwg_Attributemanager-0.3.0**

**But it has a major problem**...It doesnt show the textfields on the front-end.
(some users working 1.7.0.2 verified that happened to them)

**Does anybody know a similar stable extension for 1.7.0.2 Magento for creating custom attributes for customer during registration?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a table called `customer_form_attribute`. That one decides what attributes are shown on which forms. You need to add a record to the table with your attribute. Let's say that your new attribute has the id '25'. You need to add these lines in the table I mentioned.

```
form_code              |attribute_id
customer_account_create|25
customer_account_edit  |25
adminhtml_customer     |25
checkout_register      |25
```

The last line is not important. If you add it it will show the attribute when registering during checkout.

Comment: Thank you Marius.Give me some time to test it and I will comeback!

Comment: @kost take all the time you need.

Comment: System->Configuration->Customer Configuration->Name and Address Options->Show Middle Name (initial). Set this to `yes`. But this won't be mandatory. And it's kind of normal not to be. If you insist on making it, then look for the attribute in the table `eav_attribute` and set the value for `is_required` to 1. But I don't know the implications of this setting.

Comment: Thank you very much Marius.Helped a lot!